# how to use javascript inside of a ruby if/else statement in a js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a remotely submitted form that sometimes results in the object being deleted, but not every time, therefore I can't use redirect_to in the controller, since I will not always be redirecting...

I am trying to use window.location inside of the js.erb to change the url but i have not gotten it to work:

```
<% if @flag.save %> 
    <% if @photo.flags_count > 1 %>
      <%= @photo.update_attribute(:approved, false) %>  
      <%= flash[:success] = "Photo has been removed for review" %>
      $(window.location.href = "https://example.com/photos/");
      return
    <% else %>
```

Edit: see comments below. the issue is that the `javascript` inside of the `if/else statement` won't run.

Comment: Try using `window.location = "https://example.com/photos/"`.

Comment: this did not work.

Comment: are you sure it goes to code in `if @photo.flags_count` section? Can you try to print some text before `window.location` line and remove `return`.

Comment: you just try  window.location='/photos'

Comment: i removed `return` and tried adding `alert("hi")` underneath `<% if @photo.flags_count > 1 %>` and that also does not work. however, the script does run, i know that because when i refresh the page the model has updated. i also added `alert("hi")` to the `<% else %>` part of the statement and that also does not run, however, the ruby code underneath it continued to work.  I then placed `alert("hello")` as the very first line of code and that does work, so there is some problem with placing javascript inside of the `ruby if/else statement`

Comment: Is that the complete `js.erb`? Can you check if there is a missing `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
<%= flash[:success] = "Photo has been removed for review" %>
```

It should be:

```
<% flash[:success] = "Photo has been removed for review" %>
```